# How can I access my home folder in a live usb directly?

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, backup

I have just finished installing Ubuntu 12.04 from an 'updated' live usb. By updated I mean I had installed other softwares, removed others, run updates and upgrades, etc.

To my surprise, the newly installed system didn't come with the updates. For example, I purged libre office and installed abiword in the live session and on installing I found Libre Office. Can someone please explain to me how that worked out.

My home folder question (according to the title) is I wanted to copy my entire live usb home folder to the installed home folder including all the .folders and configurations. I just plugged in the usb directly into the newly installed 12.04 and expecting to see all the usual 'bin, boot, etc, var, lib, sys' folders, I found 'boot, capser, dists, install, pool' folders. I tried searching for my 'live session' home folder with no success. How can I access those files without booting again into the live session mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're running from a live CD / USB, ***if you enabled persistent mode when creating the drive,*** the modifications you make are stored in an "overlay" filesystem, which in turn is usually stored in a file called casper-rw on the memory stick.

You can easily access it by "loop mounting" the file, which means to treat an ordinary file like a block device and access the filesystem stored in it. If your USB stick gets mounted as, e.g. /media/USB, then the following should work:

```
sudo mount /media/USB/casper-rw /mnt -o loop
```

Then the contents of the overlay, including /home/xxx, should appear under /mnt. Note that you might have permission / ownership problems, if so try accessing /mnt as root (from the command line, after sudo -s).

Comment: So if I didn't enable persistent mode (which I don't think I did), there's no way I can access the live session files from the installed session?

Comment: Not if you've since rebooted, no. But as I said below, persistent mode is offered by default by at least one of the standard tools for creating bootable USB drives. So check for your casper-rw file, you may be in luck.

Comment: Hey, instead of mounting it under /mnt, can I use another directory coz of the permission issues? And then once I have copied my stuff, do I just delete the whole folder?

Comment: You can mount it where you like, but that actually wont help with the permissions, as they're stored in the filesystem you're mounting. Just copy the files as root if you need to, then use chown -R <user>:<group> <folder> to change the ownership of the copied files (again, if you need to - if you're the only user on both systems you should find that the user IDs match.)

Yes, Once you're sure you've got all the files you want off the USB stick, you can delete files under /mnt (or wherever you mounted it.)

Comment: I mounted it under /mnt and as root user copied my files to my new home folder. I'll now just delete the /mnt files. Will now mark this question as answered, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

So you booted from live usb, installed ubuntu on your harddrive. After this, you did not reboot, but install apps and create documents within this live system?

I must tell you, both the application changes and files created have never been somewhere else then your RAM.
So if you did a reboot (what you actually did according to your explanation), the data is gone forever.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP used persistent mode, where changes to the live system are stored in an overlay file, normally on the USB stick..

Comment: I had been working from the live usb mode which explains the 'updating'. I thought that installing the updated session would install all the updates and new softwares too. After installing I did a reboot and am working on my installed ubuntu as of right now.

Comment: If you boot from USB again, are your changes still there? Did you install it in persistent mode, like @steve asks?

Comment: Yah, everything is still the same in the USB. I don't know how to install it in persistent mode which most likely means I didn't.

Comment: If you used usb-creator-gtk to create the memory stick, I think it defaults to enabling persistence if there's room - it's the bit at the bottom of the window that asks if you want changes to be preserved..

Comment: Quickest thing is to check for the "casper-rw" file in (I think) the root directory of the USB stick.

Comment: The `casper-rw` file is there, about 4.3GB. Lemme try @SteveDee command and see...